# Qt LineTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using PyQt and want to get string from text field. I found below solution but it returns a QString. I just want to avoid writing extra code to extract string further. Can anyone suggest a simple solution to retrieve text from text field.

text = self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text()

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the text is converting the QString into a String

```
text = str(self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text())
```

Comment: Well Thanks. But can you explain that what .text() returns in actual? and how str() solved the issue?

Comment: It is a bug to convert `QString` using `str()` in Python 2. If the text contains non-ascii characters, it will raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`.